# I tried to get dynamic data from server to angular table but it's displaying only first row

Tags: javascript, angular

I tried to get dynamic data from server to angular table but it's displaying only first row

i attached the json structure with the code

component.ts

```
values:any[];

this._userService.get_user_details(this._user.role_name)
    .subscribe(
        (data: any[]) => {
          console.log('send');
      console.log(data);
      this.values=data;
    }
)
```

Service

```
get_user_details(role: string){
    return this.httpClient.post('/dashboard/api/get_user_details',{role: role});
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>YIC Id</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Controls</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let one of values ,let i = index">
      <td>{{one[i]._id}}</td>
      <td>{{one[i].name}}</td>
      <td>{{one[i].email}}</td>
      <td>{{one[i].acc}}</td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

My json data

```
[ { _id: '1',
name: 'ranjith',
email: 'ranj@xys.com',
acc: 'y',
profile_id: 'CVRsNE73.jpg' },
{ _id: '2',
name: 'Vigne',
email: 'vignesh@gmail.com',
acc: 'y',
profile_id: 'Jf0qcrVL.jpg' } ]
```

My code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly access object variable without index

```
<tr *ngFor="let one of values">
  <td>{{one._id}}</td>
  <td>{{one.name}}</td>
  <td>{{one.email}}</td>
  <td>{{one.acc}}</td>

</tr>
```

Comment: I tried you answer but its showing an empty table in it

Comment: Is this POST call or GET call? I can see you have mentioned POST..IS that correct

Comment: Cool!!..Accept the solution so that others can also get benefit

Answer (score 0):

When using `*ngFor`, you shall not use index, current row is already stored in your `one`.

use

```
<tr *ngFor="let one of values ,let i = index">
  <td>{{one._id}}</td>
  <td>{{one.name}}</td>
  <td>{{one.email}}</td>
  <td>{{one.acc}}</td>
</tr>
```

instead